# Cannot build my substrate node on nixos

Tags: substrate-node

my node builds perfectly fine on ubuntu, arch, and debian. On my nixos machine, I can build the node-template without any errors. I can also build the kitchensink node in polkadot-sdk. Buy for some reason my own node does not build with the same [flake.nix](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/flake.nix) file.

I get this error

```
   Compiling vtb-node-runtime v3.0.0-dev (/run/media/scj/Storage/Development/rust/vtb_substrate/vtb-node/runtime)
error: failed to run custom build command for `vtb-node-runtime v3.0.0-dev (/run/media/scj/Storage/Development/rust/vtb_substrate/vtb-node/runtime)`
note: To improve backtraces for build dependencies, set the CARGO_PROFILE_RELEASE_BUILD_OVERRIDE_DEBUG=true environment variable to enable debug information generation.

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/run/media/scj/Storage/Development/rust/vtb_substrate/vtb-node/target/release/build/vtb-node-runtime-654e57f79924c810/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: CARGO_TARGET_DIR="/run/media/scj/Storage/Development/rust/vtb_substrate/vtb-node/target/release/wbuild/vtb-node-runtime/target" RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=mvp -C target-feature=-sign-ext -C link-arg=--export-table -Clink-arg=--export=__heap_base -C link-arg=--import-memory  " SKIP_WASM_BUILD="" "/home/scj/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/run/media/scj/Storage/Development/rust/vtb_substrate/vtb-node/target/release/wbuild/vtb-node-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.74.0-nightly (2f5df8a94 2023-08-31)


  --- stderr
  warning: unused import: `sp_externalities::ExternalitiesExt`
   --> /run/media/scj/Storage/Development/rust/vtb_substrate/vtb-node/vtb-utils/src/offchain_extensions.rs:2:5
    |
  2 | use sp_externalities::ExternalitiesExt;
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

  warning: unused import: `string::String`
    --> /run/media/scj/Storage/Development/rust/vtb_substrate/vtb-node/vtb-primitives/src/lib.rs:12:36
     |
  12 |     use scale_info::prelude::{format, string::String};
     |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

  warning: unused import: `string::String`
     --> /run/media/scj/Storage/Development/rust/vtb_substrate/vtb-node/vtb-primitives/src/lib.rs:105:36
      |
  105 |     use scale_info::prelude::{format, string::String};
      |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  warning: `vtb-utils` (lib) generated 1 warning (run `cargo fix --lib -p vtb-utils` to apply 1 suggestion)
  warning: `ocw-primitives` (lib) generated 2 warnings (run `cargo fix --lib -p ocw-primitives` to apply 2 suggestions)
     Compiling vtb-node-runtime-wasm v1.0.0 (/run/media/scj/Storage/Development/rust/vtb_substrate/vtb-node/target/release/wbuild/vtb-node-runtime)
  error: linking with `rust-lld` failed: exit status: 1
    |
    = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="redacted"
    = note: rust-lld: error: unknown file type: /tmp/nix-shell.R2uej4/rustcuRtRpc/libsecp256k1_sys-a9a733d2c78cc86e.rlib(secp256k1.o)
            

  error: could not compile `vtb-node-runtime-wasm` (lib) due to previous error
  thread 'main' panicked at /home/scj/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-sdk-cff69157b985ed76/fcfdb98/substrate/utils/wasm-builder/src/wasm_project.rs:803:37:
  Copying the bloaty file to the project dir.: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }
  stack backtrace:
     0:     0x55555660e61c - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::libunwind::trace::h3c2e976dbdc1b990
                                 at /rustc/2f5df8a94bb3c5fae4e3fcbfc8ef20f1f976cb19/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/libunwind.rs:93:5
     1:     0x55555660e61c - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized::h0110c0bfffda25e6
                                 at /rustc/2f5df8a94bb3c5fae4e3fcbfc8ef20f1f976cb19/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/mod.rs:66:5
     2:     0x55555660e61c - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print_fmt::hcec321608a98a576
                                 at /rustc/2f5df8a94bb3c5fae4e3fcbfc8ef20f1f976cb19/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:67:5
     3:     0x55555660e61c - <std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::DisplayBacktrace as core::fmt::Display>::fmt::h5c588f6466e4fb19
                                 at /rustc/2f5df8a94bb3c5fae4e3fcbfc8ef20f1f976cb19/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:44:22
     4:     0x55555663a43c - core::fmt::rt::Argument::fmt::h6d08a5f4099d34a4
                                 at /rustc/2f5df8a94bb3c5fae4e3fcbfc8ef20f1f976cb19/library/core/src/fmt/rt.rs:138:9
     5:     0x55555663a43c - core::fmt::write::h45c64b8d2a9a9a2a
                                 at /rustc/2f5df8a94bb3c5fae4e3fcbfc8ef20f1f976cb19/library/core/src/fmt/mod.rs:1094:21
     6:     0x55555660afbe - std::io::Write::write_fmt::h06dc0395a93647bc
                                 at /rustc/2f5df8a94bb3c5fae4e3fcbfc8ef20f1f976cb19/library/std/src/io/mod.rs:1714:15
     7:     0x55555660e404 - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::h70f23affa76188de
                                 at /rustc/2f5df8a94bb3c5fae4e3fcbfc8ef20f1f976cb19/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:47:5
     8:     0x55555660e404 - std::sys_common::backtrace::print::h636df8b2fa897446
                                 at /rustc/2f5df8a94bb3c5fae4e3fcbfc8ef20f1f976cb19/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:34:9
     9:     0x55555661042a - std::panicking::panic_hook_with_disk_dump::{{closure}}::h53d60c44900d65a9
                                 at /rustc/2f5df8a94bb3c5fae4e3fcbfc8ef20f1f976cb19/library/std/src/panicking.rs:280:22
    10:     0x555556610125 - std::panicking::panic_hook_with_disk_dump::h168e84c6915dbc70
                                 at /rustc/2f5df8a94bb3c5fae4e3fcbfc8ef20f1f976cb19/library/std/src/panicking.rs:314:9
    11:     0x555556610a47 - std::panicking::default_hook::ha1bea350d7781176
                                 at /rustc/2f5df8a94bb3c5fae4e3fcbfc8ef20f1f976cb19/library/std/src/panicking.rs:239:5
    12:     0x555556610a47 - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::h8bd3ac8993dc1838
                                 at /rustc/2f5df8a94bb3c5fae4e3fcbfc8ef20f1f976cb19/library/std/src/panicking.rs:753:13
    13:     0x555556610931 - std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}::h5324e8e54853ae0e
```

I managed to build the node by adding `jemalloc` to packages in flake.nix. But now I get this when running the node.

```
Error: Service(Client(VersionInvalid("Other error happened while constructing the runtime: runtime requires function imports which are not present on the host: 'env:__stack_chk_fail'")))
2023-12-10 19:11:02 Cannot create a runtime error=Other("runtime requires function imports which are not present on the host: 'env:__stack_chk_fail'")
```

I would appriciate any help/suggestion.

Thanks.